# How to change root code like _palette(highlight)?

Tags: reactjs, highlight, gatsby

I'm searching some ways to change the default code like this one `_palette(highlight)` but I'm unable to find which file I can change to make effect everywhere in my website.

```
    &:hover {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        color: _palette(highlight) !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a file named _vars.scss, so here i can change every thing